# Is there an a way to add in dynamic values for colors and fonts in iOS?

Tags: ios

Was wondering if there was a stylesheet or an equivalent to style.xml on android to handle some dynamic values for styles to nibs?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have 2 approaches to achieving this:

1. You can use a third party library such as [Pixate Freestyle](http://www.freestyle.org) which uses CSS. You could also roll your own library to accomplish this. This is quite a heavy approach however
2. You could use a constants header file with the colors & fonts defined e.g:

   ```
   #define kPrimaryColor [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4 green:0.2 blue:0.15 alpha:1.0];
   #define kSecondaryColor [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.2 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]
   #define kPrimaryFont [UIFont fontWithName:@"name" size:12]
   #define kPrimaryFontName @"Helvetica"
   ```

   then in your code, use the defines where needed.

   ```
   textLabel.textColor = kPrimaryColor;
   textLabel.font = kPrimaryFont;
   ```

Either of these methods will work for what you need.

Comment: would it be possible to use defines in IB?

Comment: Not with defines unfortunately. With Pixate Freestyle it is possible, but it will not show the styles until run time.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and discovered that the only way to do this is by using User-Defined Runtime Attributes.

I used this example:
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/user-defined-runtime-attributes/